# When converting from Java, can gwt generate .js instead of .html files?

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

I find that GWT will generate multiples HTMLS and use frame injection to invoke the JS logic in the caller HTML. But most of the browsers will not allow you to do frame injection on a local file system.

I am trying to avoid accessing different htmls on a local file system. Is there any way to generate pure JavaScript files from GWT instead of HTML ones?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you just have to change the linker.

Add this line in your `*.gwt.xml` module file to have pure `.js` files:

```
<add-linker name="xs"/>
```

Or this one, if you want `.js` files but they are executed in an iframe context.

```
<add-linker name="xsiframe"/>
```